# How do I create a NUnit constraint with a lambda function?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, lambda, nunit

Suppose I have a class containing multiple properties:

```
class A
{
    public A(string propertyA, string propertyB)
    {
        this.PropertyA = propertyA;
        this.PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
   
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public object OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public bool HaveSameAAndB(A other)
    {
        return this.PropertyA.Equals(other.PropertyA) && this.PropertyB.Equals(other.PropertyB);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Property1 + ", " + this.Property2
    }
}
```

Now I have a [NUnit](https://nunit.org/) test project that tests whether two instances of class `A` have the same `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`

```
class ATests
{
    [Test]
    public void HaveSameAAndBTest()
    {
        var A1 = new A("wordA", "wordB");
        var A2 = new A("wordA", "wordC");

        Assert.That(A1.HaveSameAAndB(A2);
    }
}
```

This test fails with the message

> Expected: True
> But was: False

since `PropertyB` differs in both of the instances.
However, this message gives me no insight in what the result and expected result of `A1` and `A2` were.

The desired code should work something like

```
Assert.That(A1, HasConstraint(x => x.HaveSameAAndB(A2)));
```

which should fail with a message that is something like

> Expected: instance of `A`: "wordA, wordB"
> But was: instance of `A`: "wordA, wordC"

How do I achieve this?

Note that using the `ToString` method does not work for testing this method, because

```
var A1 = new A("wordA, wordB", "wordC");
var A2 = new A("wordA", "wordB, wordC");
```

have the same results for `ToString`, but have not the same `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`.

Comment: So change your ToString!

Comment: @Charlie what if I don't want to/cannot? (Since I might use ```ToString``` for a different purpose than unittesting as well)

Comment: I suppose that I can write an extension method ```PropertyAAndPropertyBToString``` that solely converts ```PropertyA``` and ```PropertyB``` to a string that I can use for unittesting